# Express.js cookie setter's Domain attribute: how to share cookie with *multiple* domains?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

Let's say you have the following cookie setter:

```
res.cookie('name', 'tobi', {
    secure: true, 
    httpOnly: false, 
    sameSite: 'None',
    domain: '.example1.com'
});
```

How would you need to change the `domain` attribute to share the cookie with **multiple** domains, and not only with example1.com?

I've tried several options for the `domain` attribute, but none worked:

```
domain: "'.example1.com','example2.com'"
domain: ['.example1.com','example2.com']
domain: "['.example1.com','example2.com']"
domain: ".example1.com", domain: "example2.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None worked because it's simply not allowed:

> [Multiple host/domain values are not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#domaindomain-value)

Also, if your website is hosted on `www.example1.com`, your server is only allowed to set cookies for either `www.example1.com` or `example1.com` (the latter meaning *"example1.com and all subdomains"*).

Comment: Thanks Robert, is there an alternative way to make a cookie accessible for multiple domains?

Comment: @Nick run a separate server on the other domains and coordinate between all servers somehow. You obviously can't set cookies for `example2.com` from the server at `example1.com` because that would mean you could set cookies for `google.com` or any other domain, posing a huge security risk.

Comment: Would the answer change if `example1.com` and `example2.com` are applications that are both run on the same server?

Comment: @Nick in short: no.

Comment: @Nick if they both run on the same server, it may easy to build a secure interaction where a page from example1.com 'controls' the cookies for example2.com. So example1.com prepares an example2.com URL including some token. That URL causes a cookie to be set for the secondary domain. Then the example1.com page loads that resource. E.g. example2.com/setcookie?token=thetokenhere. Token should be a secure id for a private data record of the cookie value, or a digest of the cookie value if the value is in the URL (if replayed it can only ever set the same value).